# How to use map function with checkbox in ReactJS?

Tags: reactjs, mern, map-function

I want to use the map function with the checkbox. I have written this code but it is giving error. how to do that

```
<div>
  <form>
   {
     data.map((x)=>{
     <input type="checkbox" />{x.name}
     }) 
     }
   </form>
 </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When using arrow functions in JavaScript, you can `return` either explicitly or implicitly.

### Explicitly

```
<div>
  <form>
     {
       data.map(x => {return <input type="checkbox" />{x.name}})
     }
   </form>
 </div>
```

### Implicitly

```
<div>
  <form>
     {
       data.map(x => <input type="checkbox" />{x.name})
     }
   </form>
 </div>
```

Doing the following will cause `data.map(x => {<input type="checkbox" />{x.name}})` to be an array of `undefined` instead of an array of inputs.

```
<div>
  <form>
     {
       data.map(x => {<input type="checkbox" />{x.name}})
     }
   </form>
 </div>
```

Answer (score 3):

You need to `return` from the map callback

```
<div>
  <form>
   {
     data.map((x) => {
       return <input type="checkbox" />{x.name}
     }) 
   }
  </form>
</div>
```

---

and you could also add a `label` around the `input` and text, so that the user can also click on the text to highlight the relevant checkbox

```
<div>
  <form>
   {
     data.map((x) => {
       return <label><input type="checkbox" />{x.name}</label>
     }) 
   }
  </form>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You should change curly braces with parentheses

```
<div>
  <form>
   {
     data.map((x)=>(
        <input type="checkbox" />{x.name}
     ) 
     }
   </form>
 </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Now that you've been helped with the checkbox syntax, I would suggest using keys when using map.

If you do not have a unique value for each item, add an index parameter in the callback function.

```
 import React from "react";
 import "./style.css";

  export default function App() {

    const list = [1,2,3,4,5];

   return (
       <div>
        <ol>
        {list.map((item, index) => 
          <li key={index}> {item} </li>
        )} 
      </ol>
      </div>

   );
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

**You should use return keyword or implicitly return**

```
<div>
  <form>
   {
     data.map(x=> (
     <input type="checkbox" />{x.name}
    )) 
   }
   </form>
</div>
```